# Unterminated group in regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I try test string using regexp in JavaScript.
Correct string looking like:

```
<script charset="utf-8">new DGWidgetLoader({"width":640,"height":600,"borderColor":"#a3a3a3","pos":{"lat":46.00650100065259,"lon":11.263732910156252,"zoom":9}
```

I want test that "width", "height" looks like xxx or xxxx, and "lat", "lon" 
looks like x{1,2}.x*, zoom looks like x{1,2}

I try use this regex

```
/<script charset="utf-8">new DGWidgetLoader(/{"width":[0-9]{3,4},"height":[0-9]{3,4},"borderColor":"#a3a3a3","pos":\{"lat":[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]+,"lon":[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]+,"zoom":[0-9][0-9]}//
```

with String.search(), but got error `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /<script charset="utf-8">new DGWidgetLoader(/{"width":[0-9]{3,4},"height":[0-9]{3,4},"borderColor":"#a3a3a3","pos":{"lat":[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]+,"lon":[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]+,"zoom":[0-9][0-9]}//: Unterminated group`

How can i parse script tag that looking like below?

Comment: There are unclosed brackets: `DGWidgetLoader({`. And the `<script>` tag isn't closed either. Is that normal?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should escape `(`, `{`, `}` and `.` with `\`:

```
/<script charset="utf-8">new DGWidgetLoader\(\{"width":[0-9]{3,4},"height":[0-9]{3,4},"borderColor":"#a3a3a3","pos":\{"lat":[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+,"lon":[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+,"zoom":[0-9][0-9]\}/
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here:

```
... DGWidgetLoader(/{ ....
```

Should be:

```
... DGWidgetLoader\(\{ ...
```

And the final slash is unnecessary in this case.

EDIT: Also, escape the final } mark and other special characters. So:

```
/<script charset="utf-8">new DGWidgetLoader\(\{"width":[0-9]{3,4},"height":[0-9]{3,4},"borderColor":"#a3a3a3","pos":\{"lat":[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+,"lon":[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]+,"zoom":[0-9][0-9]\}/
```

Also there is a small logic issue here: your zoom rule requires exactly two numerals while in practice it can be either one or two. You should consider fixing that.

Comment: This is simply wrong. It returns the same error. You also need to escape the `(`.